# How can I define my own ligatures in lualatex?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures

Why are my ligatures not working?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4page]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=pytanie.fea,
 Path = /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/,
 Extension=.ttf]{DejaVuSerif}
\begin{document}
ambona amarant żółw flaming i filharmonia.

młot
\end{document}
```

File `pytanie.fea`

```
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature liga {
 sub \a \m by \fl;
 sub 0061 by uniF731;
 sub m ł by uni0062;
} liga;
```

I need convert `am` to standard ligature `f_l`,
`a` to unicode char `F731`, and `mł` to `b`.

Comment: you do not need to specify `Path = /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/`. It is the system path and already searched for fonts.

Comment: Your use of the term "ligatures" is somewhat nonstandard: To "ligate" two or more items is to *join* them in some way. Replacing `mł` with `b` or `am` with `f_l` probably shouldn't be called ligation; I'd use the term "glyph substitution" for such an activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why the featurefile-based approach isn't working. Fortunately, though, it's not too difficult to write a Lua function and a couple of TeX-side "wrapper" macros (named `\myligsOn` and `\myligsOff`) to perform the glyph substitutions directly.

In the code below, I've switched the font from `DejaVuSerif` to `Garamond Premier Pro`, as the former doesn't seem to have a glyph at position `uniF731`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% load fontspec package and specify main font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}% -- DejaVuSerif has no glyph at pos. F731

%% Lua-side code 
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function myligs ( s )
   s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '(\\?)([%a@]+)' , function( backslash, text )
   -- no substitutions inside (La)TeX macros
       if backslash=='' then 
           text = unicode.utf8.gsub (text, 'mł', 'b' )  
           text = unicode.utf8.gsub (text, 'am', 'fl' )  
           text = unicode.utf8.gsub (text, 'a', '\\char"F731' )  
       end
       return backslash .. text
   end)
   return s
end
\end{luacode*}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\myligsOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
      "process_input_buffer", myligs, "myligs")}}
\newcommand\myligsOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
      "process_input_buffer", "myligs")}}

\begin{document}

\myligsOn
\small  % Note: The 'a' in '\small' is *not* being converted to '\char"F731'.
mł am a

\myligsOff
mł am a
\end{document}
```

Comment: Commands are not only the things with backslashs. Try out `\begin{enumerate}`. Also one would have to disable the callback at math. One the whole I find a replacement at the font label safer and easier to use as a change in the input buffer.

Comment: Wonderfull. Is posible to hypenation words with ligatures? \hyphenation{ła-ma-nie} \begin{minipage}[t]{32mm}
Test: Bo tuto nasze łamanie wiersza jest trudne. mł am ta.
\end{minipage}

Comment: is posible to add escaping other TeX constants? when i add            text = unicode.utf8.gsub (text, 'c', '\\char"F731' )
 i canot use 'cm' is possible to not using cm,mm,pt,m inch etc?

Comment: @MarkoLustro - Glad my answer is useful for you. The questions you raise in your follow-up comments are substantially new. May I therefore ask you to post new queries? By the way, are you really looking to replace (almost all) occasions of the letters `a` and `c`, or were they just meant as examples?

Comment: I create conlang, (BTW is possible to write to You email? 
my do1234staniesz_nowy@vp.pl  without numbers) I need complicated ligatures and posiblility to write sounds.

Comment: @MarkoLustro - You may find my email address on the first page of the user guide of the [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig) package.

Comment: sorry i cant find Yout email: please send me do1234staniesz_nowy@vp.pl (before deleting 1234) i'm not found in userguide

Comment: Can this code be used for replacing a sequence of characters (eg. ab) with a TeX command (eg. \textbf{ab})?