# Pass preceding character to a command LuaLaTeX

Tags: symbols, luatex, luacode

I want to make a character active/sensitive and pass its preceding character as an argument of some command. I could do it using LuaLaTeX engine and `luacode` package. Thanks to [this](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1332#a1577) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294118/how-can-i-define-my-own-ligatures-in-lualatex/294154#294154) post.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function myligs ( s )
   s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '(\\?)([%a@]+)' , function( backslash, text )
       if backslash=='' then 
           text = unicode.utf8.gsub(text, '(.)(æ)', '%1%\\textbf{%1}' )  
       end
       return backslash .. text
   end)
   return s
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", myligs, "myligs")}
aæ

bæ
\end{document}
```

but this seems to not work with dependent diacritic characters. See the following example -

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function myligs ( s )
   s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '(\\?)([%a@]+)' , function( backslash, text )
       if backslash=='' then 
           text = unicode.utf8.gsub(text, '(.)(◌́)', '%1%\\textbf{%1}' )  
       end
       return backslash .. text
   end)
   return s
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", myligs, "myligs")}

a◌́
\end{document}
```

Probably the dependent diacritic is not interpreted in the same way a normal character is. Can somebody please explain me what is exactly wrong in the second code? I want the output of both of these codes to be identical i.e. `aa` where the second `a` is bold.

Comment: The reason why your second example doesn't work is because the dependent diacritic character `◌́` does not match either element of the `[%a@]` "character class" (a Lua jargon term), i.e., either `%a` ("any alphabetic character") or `@` ("at character"). Because the `◌́` character is never matched in the first-stage or "outer" gsub operation, it doesn't get passed on to the second-stage or "inner"  gsub operation, and hence no match involving this character can ever occur in that second stage.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. This answer helped me to complete a package named `unitipa` ! I have submitted it. Soon it'll appear on the CTAN. I have cited your answer in the documentation. It helped me a lot. :) If you are curious about the package you can see it [here](https://gitlab.com/niranjanvikastambe/unitipa).

Comment: I look forward to checking out your package when it becomes available on the CTAN.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/unitipa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dependent diacritic characters are somewhat special; I will assume that they never occur inside the names of LaTeX commands and environments. If this assumption is correct, there's no need for the two-stage gsub procedure employed in your code.

The following code assumes that the character immediately before the dependent diacritic character is an alphabetic character (`%a`).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function makebold ( s )
   return ( unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '(%a)◌́' , '%1\\textbf{%1}' ) )
end
```

```
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
a◌́

% Assign 'makebold' to 'process_input_buffer' callback:
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", makebold, "makebold")}

a◌́
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. I would just like to know what does the `makebold, "makebold"` stand for?

Comment: @Niranjan - Since the Lua function doesn't appear to be related to the processing of ligatures, I thought it might be a good idea to give it a more descriptive name -- `makebold`. (You're obviously free to choose a different name.) The `luatexbase.add_to_callback` function takes three, mandatory arguments: the name of the LuaTeX callback, the name of the Lua function to be assigned to that callback, and a handle. The names of the Lua function and of the handle do not have to be identical.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation was very helpful :)

Comment: How to mark a following character in this code?

Comment: @Niranjan - Do you mean the character that follows a dependent diacritic?

Comment: Yes, I need something like this `a -> diacritic -> b` gives `\textbf{ab}`

Comment: Right now what we have is `a -> diacritic` gives `\textbf{a}`

Comment: `s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '(%a)◌́(%a)', '%1\\textbf{%1%2}' )`. The items in round parentheses before and after the dependent diacritic in the search phrase are called "captures" in Lua jargon, and they can be addressed as `%1` and `%2` in the action phrase.

Comment: Lua is just amazing! I simply love it! Thanks :)

Comment: @Niranjan - Lua's pattern-matching capabilities are indeed immensely powerful.