# Make equality-sign automatically blue

Tags: symbols, tex-core, definition, active-characters

I know that we can redefine inequality-signs such as `\le` by simply doing `\let\oldle\le` and `\def\le{\mathrel{...}}`. But I have no idea how to redefine the equality-sign `=`. So if I want to automatically make some symbols blue, I can do so for inequality-signs but not for equality-signs. What can I do to achieve automatically blue equality-signs in math mode? That is, I want to still just type `=` in math mode and it will automatically be made blue. I do not mind complicated code as long as it only needs to be inserted once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make `=` math active.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% set up = to be math active
\begingroup\lccode`~=`=\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathrel{\textcolor{blue}{\standardequal}}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\standardequal=\mathcode`= % save the standard =
  \mathcode`=="8000 % make = math active
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
a=b \\
a\standardequal b % for comparison
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I am unable to understand the line `\begingroup\lccode`~=`=\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{...}`. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @user21820 It's a very common trick for obtaining an active `=` (in this case) without doing explicit category code changes.

Comment: Can you give me a reference where I can learn this tricks and maybe other useful tricks as well? I have no idea what this one is doing.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it did what I asked for, but I still have absolutely no idea how it works, so it would be good if you can point me to some reference for at least this trick. For one, the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` do not seem matched.

Comment: @user21820 See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156759/4427

Comment: I have indeed looked at that and many other posts on TeX SE, but I couldn't find any that explained the begingroup and endgroup. From what I gather, I guess that the effect of `\lccode` somehow extends past the beginning of `\lowercase` expansion but not beyond that, but I think I am missing something.

Comment: @user21820 The argument of `\lowercase` is processed, changing letters to their lowercase counterparts based on the current values of the `\lccode` array *without changing the category code, only the character code. Then the tokens are examined anew; however, the braces have already disappeared, so the `\endgroup` balances the `\begingroup` making just the assignment to `\lccode` to be undone. Thus at the end, TeX sees `\def={...}` (but the `=` has category code 13, active).

Comment: Ahh... so it's because the lowercase of *active* `~` was defined to be `=` so... Ok thanks it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

With `LuaLaTeX`, you can do that. See the following example. (Special thanks to @Mico's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563447/174620).)

```
%!TeX Program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
    function myreplace ( s )
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , '=', '\\textcolor{blue}{=}' )
    return s
    end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",
myreplace, "myreplace")}
=
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea, because this would also match `=` in contexts like `\looseness=1`.